# Filter on TaxonomyFieldType fields using CSOM for Sharepoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

For a customer I have to retrieve a file from their sharepoint by filtering on the metadata. The two fields that I have to filter on are TaxonomyFieldType fields. I've been looking for solutions and I found some examples that show me how to filter using CAML queries, but it doesn't work for me. The list does not get filtered, instead it shows me all the files.

```
ClientContext clientContext = SP.Helpers.ConnectionHelpers.Auth(username, password, siteurl);

if (clientContext == null) return;

List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list");
clientContext.Load(oList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

View view = oList.Views.GetByTitle("view");
clientContext.Load(view);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

string query = @"<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='field' /><Value Type='Text'>filtertext</Value></Contains></Where>";
camlQuery.ViewXml = query;

ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(
            item => item.Id,
            item => item.DisplayName, item => item.Properties));

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The above code is what I came up with up to this moment. Does anyone know how to reliably filter on TaxonomyFieldTypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CamlQuery.ViewXml` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee538384(v%3Doffice.14)) expects the value in the following format:

```
<View>
   <Query>
     ...
   </Query>
</View>
```

but in your example it is not enclosed with `View` and `Query` tags, that's most likely the reason why your query is ignored and all the items are returned.

Example

```
 var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

 var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
 var query = String.Format(@"<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Contains></Where>",fieldName,fieldValue);
 camlQuery.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><Query>{0}</Query></View>", query);

 var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
 ctx.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(
            item => item.Id,
            item => item.DisplayName, item => item.Properties));

 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: It indeed was caused by the missing tags. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could try to use the following code for the query:

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='field' />
            <Value Type='Text'>filtertext</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

and replace 'field' with 'The Name of your query Field Name', and the 'filtertext' as well.

Comment: It indeed was caused by the missing tags. Thanks a lot.